# Displaying image from database on an image button in a web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to make am image from a database appear on an image button on a web form. There is no error message but the image is not appearing. Only a small small indicating that appears on the image button but not the image from the database....

My handler is here:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
{
        Int32 Member_No;
        if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
        {
            Member_No = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

            Stream strm = ShowEmpImage(Member_No);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);

            while (byteSeq > 0)
            {
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
                byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
            }  
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.Write("No Image Found");
        }
    }

   public bool IsReusable
   {
       get
       {
           return false;
       }
   }

   public Stream ShowEmpImage(int Member_No) 
   {
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyServer"].ConnectionString);
       con.Open();
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Photo from Members where Member_No = @ID", con);
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Member_No);

       object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

       try
       {
           return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
       }
       catch
       {
           return null;
       }
       finally
       {
           con.Close();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is the image itself accessible by IIS? It may be that your application is restricted from displaying the image due to permissions.

Comment: I usually start with Context.Response.Clear() because I'm always paranoid that something (unplanned) might already be in the output buffer.

Comment: i dont what is wrong because if i call the haddler using the url: MemberImage.ImageUrl = "http://localhost:56394/CallMarkSite/Pages/Handler.ashx?id=" + searchBox.Text; it is working just fine

Answer (score 0):

I would just return the `byte[]` from execute scalar and write the bytes to the stream.

```
public byte[] ShowEmpImage(int Member_No) 
{
   var settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyServer"];
   using(var con = new SqlConnection(settings.ConnectionString))
   using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Photo from Members where Member_No = @ID", con))
   {
       con.Open();
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Member_No);

       return (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   }
}

var image = ShowEmpImage(Member_No);
context.Response.WriteBytes(image);
context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
```

BTW: I would also wrap your ado.net components in `using` blocks to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: the image is appearing if i use the url:  MemberImage.ImageUrl = "http://localhost:56394/CallMarkSite/Pages/Handler.ashx?id=" + searchBox.Text;

Comment: yes, that makes sense. how else would you link to the resource?

Comment: i place them inside a folder called Pages..i just wanted the image url to be: MemberImage.ImageUrl="Pages/Handler.ashx?id="+searchBox.Text;

Comment: try "~/Pages/Handler.ashx?id="+searchBox.Text